# Load a new package in ghci using stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is there a way to load a package(s) using Stack in GHCI and play around with it ?

So, that when the `ghci` is loaded, we can import the modules and see it's type signature, etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For the packages present in Stackage,

```
$ stack ghci --package unix-time
```

And this will give you a repl with the package `unix-time` loaded in it:

```
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-6.14 from implicit global project's config file: /home/sibi/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
λ> import Data.UnixTime
λ> :t getUnixTime
getUnixTime :: IO UnixTime
```

For multiple packages:

```
$ stack ghci --package unix-time --package download
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-6.14 from implicit global project's config file: /home/sibi/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
tagsoup-0.13.10: using precompiled package
xml-1.3.14: using precompiled package
time-locale-compat-0.1.1.3: using precompiled package
feed-0.3.11.1: download
feed-0.3.11.1: configure
feed-0.3.11.1: build
feed-0.3.11.1: copy/register
download-0.3.2.4: download
download-0.3.2.4: configure
download-0.3.2.4: build
download-0.3.2.4: copy/register
Completed 5 action(s).
Configuring GHCi with the following packages:
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Ok, modules loaded: none.
λ> import Network.Download
λ>
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to specify `--package` option. You can write just `stack ghci lens mtl`

Comment: I wasn't able to load the `matrix` package without specifying the `--package` option. I had to write properly like `stack ghci --package matrix` fyi.

Comment: @Redu You are right, I have updated the answer. That only works when the package is already registred with your package database, in which case just `stack ghci` also works.

Comment: If you need a specific version of the package, something like this worked for me: `$ stack ghci --package containers-0.6.0.1`

Comment: Also, you can load a package on-the-fly while inside stack ghci using `:set -package pretty-simple`.

Comment: @AleXoundOS That only works, if your package is already registred with your local package database. If not, it doesn't work. Example:

```
λ> :set -package pretty-simple
cannot satisfy -package pretty-simple
    (use -v for more information)
```