# Split a string by a chosen character in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to split a string every time there is a chosen character. So if I receive `"1,2,3,4,5"`, and my chosen character is `","` the result is a list such as `["1","2","3","4","5"]`.

I've been looking through the already answered questions in here and they point me to using `splitOn`. However, when i try to `import Data.List.Split` in order to use it, Haskell gives me the following error: **Could not find module ‘Data.List.Split’** . When I tried to just use `splitOn`without importing the module, it showed me **Variable not in scope: splitOn**.

So my questions are,

1. Is it normal that i'm getting this error? Is `splitOn` a viable option or should I just try something else?
2. What other simple solutions are there?

I can just write something that will do this for me but I'm wondering why I'm not able to import `Data.List.Split` and if there are other simpler options out there that I'm not seeing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [GHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler) it comes with the standard Prelude and the modules in the [base package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base), and perhaps a few other packages.

Most packages, like the [split package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) (which contains the `Data.List.Split` module), aren't part of GHC itself. You'll have to import them as an explicit compilation step. This is easiest done with a build tool. Most Haskellers use either [Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/) or [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/).

With Stack, for example, you can add the `split` package to your `package.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- split
```

You can also [load an extra package when you use Stack to start GHCi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848577/126014). This is useful for ad-hoc experiments.

Answer (score 1):

‘Data.List.Split’ is not in prelude and needs to be installed as a dependency package.
Install command depends on environment you are using:
‘stack install split’ for stack
‘cabal install split’ for cabal

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is a `foldr`ing job. So you may simply do like

```
λ> foldr (\c (s:ss) -> if c == ',' then "":s:ss else (c:s):ss) [""] "1,2,3,42,5"
["1","2","3","42","5"]
```

So;

```
splitOn x = foldr (\c (s:ss) -> if c == x then "":s:ss else (c:s):ss) [""]
```

However this will give us reasonable but perhaps not wanted results such as;

```
λ> splitOn ',' ",1,2,3,42,5,"
["","1","2","3","42","5",""]
```

In this particular case it might be nice to trim the unwanted characters off of the string in advance. In Haskell though, this functionality i guess conventionally gets the name

```
dropAround :: (Char -> Bool) -> String -> String
dropAround b = dropWhile b . dropWhileEnd b

λ> dropAround (==',') ",1,2,3,42,5,"
"1,2,3,42,5"
```

accordingly;

```
λ> splitOn (',') . dropAround (==',') $ ",1,2,3,42,5,"
["1","2","3","42","5"]
```