# Splitting a list on the instance of a specific integer

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function which would split a list into few separate lists on the instance of one specific integer. Example:

`splitlist [3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 7] 0` would return `[[3, 4], [6], [7]]`

So far I've got:

```
splitlist :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
splitlist xs n 
  | length xs == 0 = []
  | head xs == n = [head (tail xs)] : splitlist (tail xs) n 
  | otherwise = [head xs : splitlist (tail xs) n]
```

However, I'm getting a type error for `head xs` in line 5:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: [Int]
        Actual type: [[Int]]
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘splitlist (tail xs) n’
      In the expression: head xs : splitlist (tail xs) n
      In the expression: [head xs : splitlist (tail xs) n]
  |
5 |   | otherwise = [head xs : splitlist (tail xs) n]
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a general advice, using `length, head, tail` is considered a bad practice when pattern matching would suffice. In the worst case, you get a crashing program, like the above one: why should `head (tail xs)` be successful on a non empty list? Often you get an inefficient program: `length xs == 0` scans the whole list to count its elements, but there is no need to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by a chosen character in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225502/split-a-string-by-a-chosen-character-in-haskell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xs` has type `[Int]`, so `head xs` has type `Int`. `splitlist` has type `[Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]`, so `splitlist (tail xs) n` has type `[[Int]]`. You're trying to call `:` on those values, which has type `a -> [a] -> [a]`. The problem is that no choice of `a` makes that work out: if you pick `Int` for `a`, then it's wrong because the second parameter is `[[Int]]` rather than `[Int]`, and if you pick `[Int]` for `a`, then it's wrong because the first parameter is `Int` rather than `[Int]`.

I think you meant to write `[head xs] : splitlist (tail xs) n` instead of `[head xs : splitlist (tail xs) n]`, like in the line above that one. However, although this type-checks, it still doesn't *work* (it produces `[[3],[4],[6],[6],[7],[7]]` on your test case, and `splitlist [0] 0` bottoms).

To actually fix it, let's first rewrite it to look a bit more idiomatic:

```
splitlist :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
splitlist [] _ = []
splitlist (x:xs) n
  | x == n = [head xs] : splitlist xs n
  | otherwise = [x] : splitlist xs n
```

The change I made is that I used pattern-matching in place of testing `length` and then using `head` and `tail`. Now the problems with the logic become apparent:

- It bottoms if the final element of the list is the separator
- The result is always a list of only single-element lists
- There's always one `Int` in the output for each `Int` in the input

I assume this is some sort of exercise, so I'm not going to spoil the final answer. However, this should be enough to get you going again.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I tried to use `[head xs : splitlist (tail xs) n]` was because I was trying to fix the second problem that you pointed out - that it's always a list of only single element lists. I'm still not sure how to do this - I'm trying to put x as the first element of the list and then call the function again, but I'm still getting the type errors and I'm not too sure how to avoid that. I also tried using ++, but I don't think that's allowed in pattern matching.