# How to import Math.X in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like to use [Math.NumberTheory.Moduli.Class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.10.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli-Class.html) in my Haskell program. It doesn't seem to be included in Prelude since when I try to use it in GHCI

```
> (3 :: Mod 5) + (4 :: Mod 5)
```

we have `Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Mod’`. I also can't seem to import it into GHCI since none of the following work

```
> import Math.NumberTheory.Moduli.Class
> import Math.NumberTheory.Moduli
> import Math.NumberTheory
```

because "Could not find module". Finally,

```
cabal install Math.NumberTheory
```

seems to have no knowledge of any such package names "Math". Moreover, I can't figure out how to use *any* of the packages in `Math.NumberTheory`. How does one import these into a Haskell program?

Comment: The question is about a different package than the one [asked about here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59225974/126014), but the answer ought to be the same. I wonder if we should close this as a duplicate?

Comment: The package name is `arithmoi`. See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48855060/126014

Comment: There are a lot of concepts that you are misunderstanding/not aware of here, and I do not have time to write a full answer. For helpfulness's sake, you should be able to incant `cabal v2-repl -b arithmoi`, and then import your desired modules.

Comment: Cabal deals with *packages*, a package is a collection of *modules*. `Math.NumberTheory` is a *module*.

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't seem to be included in Prelude

Prelude is a module, not a package, and thus can not include other modules.  You probably mean "base".

> cabal install Math.NumberTheory seems to have no knowledge of any such package names "Math"

Because that is a module name, not a package which is a collection of modules (roughly).  You need to tell cabal to install the package not the module.

Try instead:

```
cabal install arithmoi
ghci
import Math.NumberTheory.Moduli.Class
```

Or as a project-in-a-file:

```
$ cat so.hs
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
        build-depends: base, arithmoi
-}

module Main where

import Math.NumberTheory.Moduli.Class

main :: IO ()
main = return ()
$ chmod +x so.hs ; ./so.hs 2>/dev/null 1>&2 ; echo $?
0
```