# how do I install `Test.QuickCheck` GHCi can't find it, import fails

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm on macOS running stack/GHCi version 8.4.3:

`import Test.QuickCheck`  fails at both the GHCi prompt and in my .hs files. Either way I'm told it's not found.
GHCi Prelude>

```
<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

in .hs file >

```
"Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’ '
```

The source code is [on this page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) but I'm not sure how to install a new package into stack manually. From my brief reading when I googled "install Haskell package" it suggests installing a cabal package universally is a [bad idea](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/How_to_install_a_Cabal_package). Not sure this is a cabal package, and in any case it would be good to be able to import it for any project I think in my case.

Comment: You need to install the corresponding package with a package manager, for example `cabal`, so `cabal install QuickCheck`.

Comment: Thanks, reading the cabal QuickStart guide this is amazingly not clear like that!

Comment: does the directory from which I issue the command matter to where it is installed? I want it in the central repository, although I'm not sure where cabal put that in the first place.

Comment: If you're using Stack, you can [add packages to a GHCi session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848577/126014). For compiled code, you should create a Stack project with `stack new` and then add packages to the project configuration files. There's a few alternative ways to do this, so consult [the documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org).

Comment: `cabal install QuickCheck` is exactly the thing your "bad idea" link is warning against.

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to do this for a quick ghci session is to use `cabal repl` and add a dependency on `QuickCheck`:

```sh
% cabal repl --build-depends QuickCheck
> import Test.QuickCheck
Test.QuickCheck> -- ^_^
```

For longer-term programming (i.e. not just quick tests of stuff in ghci), the modern way is to create a cabal package and add `QuickCheck` to the build-depends section in the `*.cabal` produced:

```sh
% mkdir fancy-package
% cd fancy-package
% cabal init
<follow prompts>
% $EDITOR fancy-package.cabal
<find build-depends: and add, for example, QuickCheck ^>= 2.14 to the list>
% cabal repl
*Main> import Test.QuickCheck
*Main Test.QuickCheck> -- ^_^
```